# Django. Выбрать только один связанный объект с наименьшей ценой

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...


class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField()
    ...
```

Как одним запросом выбрать Product и связанный с ним ProductVariant, но только один и с наименьшей ценой?

**views.py**

```
class ProductList(generic.ListView):
    model = Product
```

**template**

```
{% for product in product_list %}
<div class="product-card">
    {{ product.name }}
    <!--
        Вот тут хотелось бы иметь доступ к варианту товара,
        при этом не генерировать множество запросов.
    -->
    {{ product.variant.price }}
    {{ product.variant.color }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Какие именно данные вы ожидаете на выходе?

Comment: Добавил в сам вопрос, думаю теперь будет понятнее.

Comment: как насчет того чтобы добавить метод в класс `ProductVariant`, который будет возвращать сущность с меньшей ценой?

Comment: Это создаст множество запросов к бд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['price']
    ...
```

`ordering` указывает сортировку по умолчанию для модели

```
{% for product in product_list %}
<div class="product-card">
    {{ product.name }}
    <!--
        Вот тут хотелось бы иметь доступ к варианту товара,
        при этом не генерировать множество запросов.
    -->
    {{ product.variant.0.price }}
    {{ product.variant.0.color }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

Если будут лишние запросы, используйте `select_related`
```